# Tweepy: how to scrape hashtags

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I am scraping several twitter profiles profiles with the V1.1 api, and it works all fine and dandy using the method

```py
api.user_timeline(screen_name = profile, count = n, tweet_mode = "extended", exclude_replies = True)
```

How can I scrape hashtags? and I don't want to scrape them specifically from given profiles.
For instance I'd like to scrape all tweets that have a given hashtag form a specific date onward or the last N tweets with that hashtag regardless of the profile tweeting it.

Any tips?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [api.search()](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#search-tweets) method ?

You can use it to get the tweets containing some hashtag:

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#myHashtag').items():
    print(tweet)
```